# All matrices with eigenvectors 1 and given eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I need to find all matrices $B$ (apart from identity) that satisfy - $$AB = A$$
 for a given $A$. This means that the rows of $A$ have to be the eigenvectors of $B$ and all eigenvalues of $B$ should be 1. One thing worth noting is that $B$ can't be diagonalizable since if it were, the condition that all eigenvalues should be 1 would leave us with only the identity matrix.

Is there a general way to find all $B$s?

Comment: What is the field of definition of these matrices?

Comment: Note: it is not necessary that **all** eigenvalues of $B$ are $1$, only that the rows of $A$ are each left-eigenvectors to $B$.  This guarantees that $B$ has a (left-)eigenspace for $1$ equal to the range of $A$ (so the geometric multiplicity is the rank of $A$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $B$ must be square.  We can rearrange your equation to get
$$
A(B - I) = 0
$$
where $I$ denotes the identity matrix. Let $M$ denote the matrix $B - I$.  Let $x_1,\dots,x_n$ denote the columns of $M$.  We then have
$$
A(B - I) = AM = A [\;x_1 \quad x_2 \quad \cdots \quad x_n \;] = 
[\;Ax_1 \quad Ax_2 \quad \cdots \quad Ax_n \; ]
$$
and all of these columns must be zero.

In summary:

> $B$ will satisfy $AB = A$ if and only if $B$ is of the form $M + I$, where $M$ is a matrix whose columns $x_1,\dots,x_n$ all satisfy $Ax_i = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

First, note that if $A$ is invertible, then the only possibility for $B$ is the identity. More generally, the number of Jordan blocks of $B$ is the dimension of the row space of $A.$ You can go from there, in case your field is $\mathbb{C}.$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom the OP points out in the question that you can :)

Comment: I realized after commenting -_-